# How to prevent browser from opening .csv file?

Tags: javascript, html, web

We are working on an embedded web application that is deployed on embedded GoAhead Web Server. It has .CSV files available for download. However when we click on the link the browser opens the CSV file instead of downloading it. We want the file to be downloaded when user clicks on a link instead of opening it. I know user can download by right clicking on link and using "Save link as" menu option :) but that is not what the client wants. How can we achieve this? Is JavaScript the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to send the right header and the right content-disposition.

the content-disposition should be attachement.